# Odoo can't open form view from wizard on button click

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9, wizard

I have created wizard. And on button click I want to open form view with specific model record id.

```
@api.multi
def create_order(self):
    view = self.env.ref('purchase.purchase_order_form')
    context = self.env.context
    return {
         'name':'Name',
         'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
         'view_type': 'form',
         'view_mode': 'form',
         'res_model': 'purchase.order',
         'views': [(view.id, 'form')],
         'view_id': view.id,
         'res_id': 264,
         'context': context,
    }
```

The problem is that on button click I can't open other form view.

If I add 'target': 'new', then on button click on popup window I open form which I need:

```
   @api.multi
    def create_order(self):
        view = self.env.ref('purchase.purchase_order_form')
        context = self.env.context
        return {
             'name':'Name',
             'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
             'view_type': 'form',
             'view_mode': 'form',
             'res_model': 'purchase.order',
             'views': [(view.id, 'form')],
             'view_id': view.id,
             'target': 'new',
             'res_id': 264,
             'context': context,
        }
```

The problem is that on button click I need to open specific form but like popup window.
I tried set 'target': 'inline' or 'target': 'current' but nothing happens.

Comment: Try to remove keys from dict 'views' ,  'target' , 'res_id' and give value to key 'view_id' : False and relaod again.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem will resides on your param res_id, this is not needed actually. its only return the record of res_id if exists. Any way I give you an valid example. so please try:

```
return {
        'name': _('Compose Email'),
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'mail.compose.message',
        'views': [(compose_form.id, 'form')],
        'view_id': compose_form.id,
        'target': 'new',
        'context': ctx,
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I said in my question if I am using 'target': 'new' everything is ok but I don't want open my form in popup window...

Comment: Then there is no problem i can see, you can use target = "current". This should works.

Answer (score 0):

What model/record is this being called from? For example, are you adding this to a Sales Order or some other model's form?

If so, you may need to set include the Source Model, such as:

```
'src_model': 'sale.order',
```

In the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html#launching-wizards), this is used for launching wizards and *may* be needed for redirecting the model.

Comment: The problem is when I click on button on wizard popup view to open new view.

Answer (score 0):

**SEE AT THE END OF THE RESPONSE FOR A SIMPLER SOLUTION**

I had the same problem but I was able to resolve it. I must say that I am using a old OpenERP version (5.0.14), so maybe it does not work with you.

```
    model_obj = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    res_id = model_obj.get_object_reference(cursor, uid,
                                            'your_model',
                                            'your_view_id_ref_defined_in_xml')[1]

    return {
        'name': 'View name, anything you want',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'view_model',
        'domain': "[('id', 'in', {})]".format(ids_to_show),
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_id': (res_id, 'View'),
    }
```

Using the question example it will be:

```
    model_obj = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    res_id = model_obj.get_object_reference(cursor, uid,
                                            'purchase',
                                            'purchase_order_form')[1]

    return {
        'name': 'View name, anything you want',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'purchase.order',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_id': (res_id, 'View'),
    }
```

Hope it helps!

**SIMPLER SOLUTION**

Another, maybe simpler and cleaner solution is to set the view_id to False  and set the view that you want to load in the context. You can specify what view you will load for the tree part with *'tree_view_ref'* and the form part with *'form_view_ref'*.

Here is an example loading a view called *custom_stock_tree_view* and *custom_stock_form_view* defined in a module called *custom_stock*

```
   return {
        'name': 'Custom Stocks',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree,form',
        'res_model': 'stock.move',
        'view_id': False,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'context': {
            'tree_view_ref':
                'custom_stock.custom_stock_tree_view',
            'form_view_ref':
                'custom_stock.custom_stock_form_view'
        }
    }
```

Please, note that the view_id is set to False. Otherwise it will not load the desired view (Thanks to Joan M. Grande, who saw this).